# Как сделать чтобы сочетание клавиш работало как нажатие на другую клавишу

Tags: linux, gnome, manjaro, x11, shortcuts

Для удобства печати хочу сделать, чтобы при нажатии на комбинацию:

- caps + j - курсор передвигался влево (нажатие трактовалось как нажатие клавиши
  влево)
- caps + l - вправо
- и т.д.

Подскажите, в какую сторону искать чтобы это сделать?
Сижу на Manjaro(дистрибутив основанный на Arch Linux), среда рабочего стола GNOME 3.

**UPD**

Попытался использовать xkb для этих целей.
Для этого создал `~/.config/xkb/symbols/my` файл следующего содержания:

```
xkb_symbols "my" {
    include "pc+us+ru:2+ua:3+inet(evdev)+level3(caps_switch)"
    key <AC07> { [ j, J, Left ] };
    key <AC09> { [  l, L, Right ]};
    key <AC08> { [  k, K, Down ]};
    key <AD08> { [  i, I, Up ]};
    key <AD07> { [  u, U, Delete ]};
    key <AD09> { [  o, O, BackSpace ]};
    key <SPCE> { [ space, space, End, nobreakspace ] };
};
```

Потом применил эти изменения:

```
setxkbmap -symbols my -print | xkbcomp -I"$HOME/.config/xkb" - "${DISPLAY%%.*}"
```

Это работает, но не во всех программах. Например, в gedit это работает, а вот в Intellij IDEA - нет. Насколько я понимаю, проблема состоит в том, что вместе с нужным keysym XKB отправляет флаг состояния клавиш модификаторов(`state`), в котором устанавливает один з флагов модификаторов(видимо mod5). Часть програм игнорирует состояния этих флагов, используя только keysym, а часть нет.
Вот вывод `xev -event keyboard` при нажатии на клавишу 'j'

```
KeyPress event, serial 25, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x1a9, subw 0x0, time 12058152, (848,636), root:(924,742),
    state 0x10, keycode 44 (keysym 0x6a, j), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (6a) "j"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (6a) "j"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

А вот при нажатии комбинации 'caps + j'

```
KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x1a9, subw 0x0, time 12064539, (848,636), root:(924,742),
    state 0x90, keycode 44 (keysym 0xff51, Left), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 113
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Каким образом можно заставить XKB не выставлять этот флаг?

Comment: интересный вопрос... capslock при этом планируешь для чего-то использовать как самостоятельную клавишу? если да, то, скорей всего, без патчинья иксов лёгкой кровью не отделаешься (могу ошибаться)... если нет, то я бы попробовал сделать её ещё одним модификатором и уже `ModN+<что-то там>` привязать на то что нужно... для второго сценария копать в сторону того, как в иксах задаётся мапинг клавиш, я бы начал с `xmodmap` (я не знаю, работает ли он хоть как-то в современных дистрах) и `xkb`... на уме крутятся ещё пара альтернативных более странных вариантов...

Comment: в качестве бреда: еще к этому можно подступиться со стороны железа =)

Answer (score 2):

Caps Lock не является [модификатором](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80), по этому даже если вы найдёте решение, оно будет костыльным и идеологически неверным. Используйте другую клавишу, например Super. Для этого можно назначить хоткей для команды вроде `xdotool key Right` в настройках системы (в гноме эта менюшка выглядит так):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это работает, но слишком медленно, к тому же при нажатии и удерживании, например alt + j, курсор перемещается только на одну позицию, тоесть удерживание alt + j трактуется как разовое нажатие стрелки влево.

Comment: @Asem У xdotool много разных опций. Используйте вместо **key** комбинации из **keydown** и **keyup**, а также обратите внимание на **--clearmodifiers** https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-xdotool/#lbAE

Comment: @Asem хотя пожалуй да, конкретно в вашем случае проблема не в том, чтобы послать сигнал клавиатуры, а в том, что через стандартные настройки системы нельзя отдельно забиндить keyup/keydown у основного сочетания. Боюсь, тут нужно искать стороннюю программу, которая более детально "прослушивает" клавиатуру. Увы, я о таких ничего не знаю, хотя уверен что они существуют.